# Is using required for both HttpClient instantiation AND request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In this code:

```
using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
{
    using var request = await httpClient.DeleteAsync($"https://somesite.com");
}
```

Is the second `using` required or is it redundant?

Answer (score 0):

The `using` statement is there to `Dispose` of the `HttpClient` object once it's gone out of its scope. The second `using` does the same for the `HttpResponseMessage`. You can read about disposing it [here](https://www.stevejgordon.co.uk/demystifying-httpclient-internals-httpresponsemessage), but generally this should cover it:

> In the majority of cases, the body of the response from the underlying
>   connection (Socket) is fully received, and the byte data, representing
>   the content will be buffered into a memory stream automatically. This
>   occurs when using most overloads of the HttpClient APIs (GetAsync,
>   PostAsync and SendAsync).
>
> Once data has finished buffering, the underlying connection which was
>   used to make the request will go idle and be marked as having
>   completed. It will also be disassociated from the HttpContentStream
>   and therefore be available to handle further requests via the
>   HttpClient.
>
> When calling dispose manually on HttpResponseMessage, in the above
>   case, since the connection is already released the call to Dispose
>   will merely dispose of the HttpContent MemoryStream.

For best practice you can read:

> The safest, general advice would be to always dispose of the
>   HttpResponseMessage once you have finished with using it. This does
>   lead to a little more code noise but ensures that regardless of the
>   internals and any future changes, your code will free/clean up unused
>   resources such as connections as quickly as possible. Be aware that
>   once you dispose of the content, it will become unusable for anyone
>   else who has been passed a reference to it.

That being said, I've never done it myself and never had any problems with it ;)

May I add... 
The using statement is useful, but it does cause issues with `HttpClient`. Please refer to [this article](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

I used to create a `IHttpClientFactory` interface with a private instance of `HttpClient` within while using .NET Framework, then injecting it in API calling class(es).

Please note, that .NET Core [provides a way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) to inject `HttpClient` very easily.

Essentially, what happens is, in your `Startup.cs` class

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpClient<OAuthClient>(client =>
        {
            // you can configure your httpclient here
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.example.com/api/v3");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "accessToken");
        });
    }
```

And then inject in other classes:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private HttpClient _client;

    public SomeClass(HttpClient client)
    {
        _client = client;
    }
    public async Task GetStuffFromAPI(string requestUrl)
    {
        await _client.GetAsync(reqestUrl);();
    }
```

What happens with the above is: every time you inject `HttpClient`, it'll first try to inject the instance you've specified in your `Startup` class. There's much more to it, but I'll keep this answer simple